# David Innes in League of Extraordinary Gentlemen?

Tags: comics, league-of-extraordinary-gentlemen

Is [David Innes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Innes) or [Pellucidar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pellucidar) ever mentioned in the [*League of Extraordinary Gentlemen*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_of_Extraordinary_Gentlemen) comics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe John Carter is the only character from Edgar Rice Burroughs to make an appearance in the League.

Here's a [complete listing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_League_of_Extraordinary_Gentlemen_characters) of characters appearing in or mentioned in the graphic novels.